# How to change the javascript of a page dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select object like :

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange = "start()" >
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Now, I want to change the JavaScript as per the value of mySelect. For example, if its value is "Apple" then I want to set the JavaScript to "Apple.js". Also, I have an existing JavaScript in the page which contains the function start(). I want the new JavaScript to override the existing JavaScript. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load script dynamically:

```
$.loadScript('Apple.js', function(){//url you can specify
    //Yayhhh!! your script loaded
});
```

or use [**getscript()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    //Yayhhh!! your script loaded
});
```

As you have mentioned `start()` on `onchange()` event your can use:

HTML snippet:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange = "start(this.value)" >
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^====>passing current selected value
```

Script:

```
var start = function(val){
    if(val == 'Apple'){
        $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
          console.log( data ); // Data returned
          console.log( textStatus ); // Success
          console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
          console.log( "Load was performed." );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell what does `function( data, textStatus, jqxhr )` do?

Comment: I have added some information of this function. Here you can find more information https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

```
function start(){
  console.log("test");
}
function start(){
 console.log("test2");
}

start()
```

Try to execute this code in Console panel in your browser. You will see it's show you test2. When you load a new function with same name as before it's simply override the old function with new one.

Simply load the javascript through [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) will make your function loaded from a new file.